# Single Sign-On and Multi-Factor Authentication

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

Please, I need some informations about Single Sign-On and Multi-Factor Authentication on MC platform:

1. Marketing Cloud Single Sign-On (SSO) is not compatible with Multi-Factor Authentication. If you are using SSO for Marketing Cloud login management, it is still recommended that you enable multi-factor authentication for your Identity Provider (IdP) as an additional security measure. Is there a discrepancy?
2. For integration users, with MFA, are there any impacts (Api User)?
3. Should SSO be enabled for non-technical users only?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MC MFA does not work with SSO, the recommendation is to enable some type of MFA with your SSO solution.

Review this help doc for additional answers: '[Marketing Cloud Multi-Factor Authentication FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_mfa_faq_main.htm&type=5)'

> Does MFA Affect API Integrations?
> No, multi-factor authentication (MFA) only affects authentication for users who log in to Marketing Cloud via their browser or the Marketing Cloud mobile app. MFA does not affect REST or SOAP API requests.

But you should also be using a token for API calls instead of UN/PW

Comment: Thank you so much